# Finding a better way to say "put to good use"

Tags: synonyms

Better way to say:  "put to good use"

Trying to figure out in terms of being accountable with resources. Specifically, in this sentence:

> every cent of funding could be *put to good use*

I think it sounds passive, but am blocked.

Answer (score 4):

You could say *efficiently Allocated*;  this generally has the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

One common expression is [capitalise [on]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/capitalize) *7 - to take advantage of; turn something to one's advantage (often followed by on ): to capitalize on one's opportunities.*

Although it's often used with the literal sense *turn into capital, make money from*, it's also commonly used metaphorically to mean *take advantage of, make best use of*.

Answer (score 1):

*They were thrifty with every cent of funding.*

[*Thrifty* means](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thrifty) "careful and diligent in the use of resources."

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that the funds were aptly *[appropriated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appropriate)*:

> : to set apart for or assign to a particular purpose or use
>
> Ex. *appropriate money for the research program*

This would be in direct opposition to *misappropriated* funds or resources.

Comment: *Appropriated* leaves room for misinterpretation.  You've given sense 2 from the link; sense  3 is "to take or make use of without authority or right", ie to misappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I think *fully utilized* or *responsibly used* might give you the connotations of accountability you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider "the value [or effect] of the funding could be *maximized*."

Answer (score 0):

**employed** is a good, single-word answer that has the connotation of being effectively used.

> To put (something) to use or service: employed [thefreedictionary.com]

Example sentence: *"Knives were employed in the cutting process."*

Answer (score 0):

- profitized
- used wisely
- used effectively

Comment: Please explain why you think those would be good alternatives. Especially the first one which might not exist.

Comment: the words are self-explanatory. and the first one does exist, though used very rarely. then again, if someone wanted to go with something commonly used and understood, there'd be no point in asking for alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

I would write:

> Every cent of funding could be used to buy ice cream

There you go :) money well spent!